# Simplest way to serve static file as JSON

Tags: json, amazon-s3

I want to serve a very simple text file as JSON for my iOS app to get data from at launch.

The file structure is very simple, would contain one JSON object, something like this:

```
{
    "id": "957ehco3",
    "name": "Display Name",
    "link": "www.link.com",
    "width": 500,
    "height": 200
}
```

It would be periodically updated, but could be updated manually—does not need to be updated via a JSON request.

If possible, I would like to serve it from S3, with some kind of authentication about the source. I would like to avoid a dedicated server/framework to serve this one file.

What is the most lightweight way to do this?

Comment: This "one" file... would it be identical for every user, or different?

Comment: It would be the same for everyone. The reason I want to have it served as JSON instead of bundled in the app is so that I can update the content without having to depend on an app update.

Comment: And what does "authentication about the source" mean?  You want the app to authenticate the contents of the file, or you want S3 to authenticate that it is a request from your app?

Comment: I want the app to authenticate that it is coming from my JSON endpoint. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The most lightweight solution?

- use a bucket without any dots in the name, with a DNS valid name, which starts with [a-z] and contains only [a-z] [0-9] [-] in its bucket name
- store file in bucket, remembering to set an appropriate `Cache-Control` header (`max-age=0` while testing)
- make it publicly readable
- access it from the app using the **HTTPS** REST endpoint for the bucket

With HTTPS, the request and the response are encrypted, as you know, but the host is also authenticated, because the SSL certificate presented by the web server contains the hostnames it is authorized to represent, and the request will fail.  So, if I set up my web server and call it `example-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com` and manage to hijack a DNS server somewhere, convincing it to return my IP address instead of a genuine S3 IP address, an HTTPS client will refuse to negotiate HTTPS with my fraudulent, impostor web server, because my server doesn't possess an SSL cert that was signed by a certificate authority that is trusted by the client (browser, app) authorizing my web server to represent itself as `example-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com`.

Or, still relatively lighweight but a much steeper learning curve... as above with an addition: depending on just how important it is to you that the data be difficult for even the most determined abuser to spoof, sign the payload using a public/private keypair, include the signature in the S3 metadata, embed the *public* key in the app, and verify that the received data matches the signature.  This could be done with openssl tools when you create the file, and java crypto functions inside the app.

The mechanism I'm envisioning here is similar to a mechanism that Amazon SNS uses to prove to an application that HTTP push messages supposedly from SNS are genuinely SNS, and that EC2 uses to prove that an instance identity document was issued by AWS.

But *caveat lector*, of course, because you shouldn't accept security advice you read on the Internet. :)